# SIM card contacts in ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI

Tags: android, android-contacts

From which sources can I expect data using `ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI`. In particular, I'm interested if SIM card contacts are included.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to all Contacts from Sim Card then try below Code:

```
private void SIMContacts()
  {
    try
    {
        String strPhonename = null; 
        String strphoneNo = null;

    Uri simUri = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn"); 
    Cursor cursorSim = this.getContentResolver().query(simUri,null,null,null,null);

    while (cursorSim.moveToNext()) 
    {      
        strPhonename =cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex("name"));
        strphoneNo = cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex("number"));
        strphoneNo.replaceAll("\\D","");
        strphoneNo.replaceAll("&", "");
        strPhonename=strPhonename.replace("|","");

        Log.i("Contact: ", "name: "+strPhonename+" phone: "+strphoneNo);
    }        
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: so does this this mean that contacts from SIM Card are not included in ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI?

Comment: Wrong. Sim contacts ARE included in ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI. They are hidden only if the user choose to hide the Sim contacts from the device settings

Comment: The sim contacts behavior differs between devices, some devices like Samsung's return SIM contacts from the Contacts table, others, like Nexus devices do not.

Comment: @Riser this is ok i understand but i want to know if  device  have two sim then how i will get both sim URI so that we can get Contact of both sim ???